# GUIZERO - How to update text and pictures on a screen after variables have changed

Tags: python, image, text, guizero

I am using GUIZERO to create a gui that displays text and picutres. The functions in my program take a while to complete, and so to avoid errors when all the screens are created when the program is first run, I have set defult values at the start of the code.
However, when the functions are run the variables and the pictures are overwritten, I have no way of updating them on the screen so the text and pictures are stuck at default values.

```
sevendaygraph = Picture(screen4box10, image="7day.png", grid=[0,1], width = 500, height= 250, visible=True)
```

I can see that the picture has been overwritten becuase the new image is there in files.
I have tried updating the screen with the new image using

```
 screen.update()
```

However this does nothing.
GUIZERO also has a destroy command but no way of initializing it again.

How can I update the screen with new values?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The code you have given has nothing wrong with it. You need to add how you are tying to change it, screen.update just refreshes the window.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.